# a vb problem with getting the file name out of the file path name

Tags: vb.net

A label on a form requires the file name to be inserted when loading a new file I think I know where the error is but don't know how to fix it. The problem is getting the File name from the path returned from the load routine

the code

```
 Private Sub LblLoadSavedPrompt1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LblLoadSavedPrompt1.Click
        Dim IntLs0 As Integer, IntLs1 As Integer, IntLs2 As Integer, IntLs3 As Integer
        LoadSaved()
        IntLs0 = StrGN.Count                                                    ' StrGN = StrFileName used in LoadSaved()  OK
        IntLs2 = 0 '-1-
        IntLs3 = 0 '-2-
        For IntLs1 = IntLs0 To 0 Step -1                                        ' IntLs1 =  From IntLs0 to 0
            If StrGN.Substring(IntLs1, 0) = "." Then IntLs2 = IntLs1 '-3-            ' IntLs2 should be Possition of "." from end of string  in StrGN
            If StrGN.Substring(IntLs1, 0) = "S" And IntLs2 > IntLs1 Then '-5-       ' IntLs3 should be Next occurance of 'S' from Location of "." 
                IntLs3 = IntLs1 ' -4-
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        LblGridNumber.Text = StrGN.Substring(IntLs3, (IntLs2 - IntLs3))         ' alwasys shows "      " should be "SH91" for the  file being used
        lblStatusMessage1.Text = IntLs3.ToString() & "," & IntLs2.ToString()    ' Always shows 0 , 0  should be :- 37 , 41 at this point
        BtnSolve1.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

If I change IntLs2 at -1- to 41 and IntLs3 at -2- to 37 correct result appears return them to 0 the label goes back to blank.
If i change IntLs1 at -3- to 41 and IntLs1 at -4- to 37 then label is still blank if i remove the 'and IntLs2 > IntLs1' at section at -5- I get the same negative result, I have been trying to sort this for 4 Hrs
Have narrowed the problem down to the two if lines inside the for next loop.

Comment: I am not sure to have understood the code presented here. But to extract a filename from a path name you have the _Path.GetFileName(fullPath)_ Please look at the [Path class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.8) on Docs. Is _StrGN_ the variable that holds the full path from which you want to extract the filename part?

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Right now you've just shown us how you've tried to do "it" but haven't defined what "it" is.

Comment: sorry as to the what it is to extract the file name ( SH91 ) in this case, to show on screen which file is being worked on.           i will check the path class on docs yes the StrGN is the variable

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the easy route as it will only be me using it.
Message box at start of save routine says Must start with an Ucase "S" And Size of grid
Max 7 characters and pad out with spaces
then replaced the above routine with

```
 Dim IntLs0 As Integer
        LoadSaved()
        StrGN = StrFileName
        IntLs0 = StrGN.Count
        LblGridNumber.Text = StrGN.Substring(IntLs0 - 11, 7).TrimEnd()
        lblStatusMessage1.Text = IntLs0 - 10.ToString() & "," & IntLs0 - 6.ToString()
        BtnSolve1.Visible = True
```

Work as long as File name is 7 sharacters long only